# How can I create editable AMPscript in Content Builder?

Tags: ampscript

We are transferring our Classic Content emails over to Content Builder. We have an email that uses a full screen image as a background for email clients that support it.

[image: full screen image]

We have built a template in content builder that supports the full screen image by modifying the full HTML code in the template. Because you can't edit that section of the HTML when building an actual email (as opposed to a template), the plan was to use an HTML block above the logo filled with AMPscript to fill in the img url. This would allow us to simply modify the HTML block in Content Builder, instead of having to create a new "template" just to change an image.

```
<!-- HTML directly under ending head tag -->
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="background-image:url('%%=v(@BGIMG)=%%'); background-size: cover;background-position:0% 0%;background-color:#C9C9C9;background-repeat: no-repeat;-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);" background="%%=v(@BGIMG)=%%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
```

....

```
<!-- hidden HTML block within Content Builder --> 
%%[/* Script <div style="display:none"> */ 
VAR @BGIMG 
/* Modify this to set header background image */ 
SET @BGIMG = "http://image.e.dupagecu.com/lib/fe96127276600c7c74/m/2/7e814c0a-6773-45a8-9e9f-3394a5d5e596.jpg?b=1522249131000"  
 /* </div> */ ]%%
```

This issue is that this content block appears *below* the table coding with the background image. Anyone have any ideas for a workaround? Ideally we would be able to edit something directly in Content Builder.